# How to use mobile wi-fi to connect Internet?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, tethering

I am using a Samsung mobile , which is having WI-fi feature . Now I am here to request that is there any way i can use the mobile WI-FI modem to connect the Internet through the PC ? I mean , that wifi modem will list in my PC available Network connections ?

As suggested i am giving the image of my phone and its specification link .

[image]

[Click here for Phone information.](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_c6712_star_ii_duos-3921.php)

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. (a) Use the mobile phone's data service and tether the PC using Wifi? Or (b) Use the PC's cable Internet and use the PC as an access point to browse the Internet on the mobile phone? If (a) your phone (mobile carrier) may not allow it. You may have to root the phone and download something on the phone. If (b) Android phones do not display ad-hoc Wifi hotspots. Again you may have to root the phone and download something on the phone.

Comment: How you connect your PC to internet with mobile ?  you gonna use it as a modem right . as in the same way now i'd like to use my wi-fi modem of mobile as a modem to connect to Internet .

Comment: This mostly works out of the box in Ubuntu. I remember my SE W800 did so by plugging it in via USB, works just like a USB stick. @user68186 Exactly some carriers don't allow so called tethering and remove the functionality on the phones they provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My phone is a Galaxy SII, so YMMV (your menus may vary) =).

What I just did was:

1. Disable my Ethernet card.
2. Connected my phone to my WiFi.
3. Connected the phone to my PC with a USB cable.
4. In the main screen of the phone selected Config > Wireless and Web Connections > More...
5. Mobile Zone and Web Tethering.
6. Enabled "Tether to USB net" (or web, in Spanish it's 'red')
7. Enabled Mobile Wi-Fi Zone.
8. Configured it (Wep, etc.)
9. In PC, open connections connections and selected "Wired Connection 'n'" (Conexión Cableada 'n', in Spanish). My actual number was 2 FWIW.

Connection info reports it as "usb0"

It linked immeditely, I'm using it to write this.

Good luck!

Comment: OK, missed the not Android part. Sorry. In any case, I'm pretty sure most any smartphone will work as a WiFi modem. Try to find its manual in the web —probably a pdf and you should be able to find it in the Samsung site under support– then do a search for modem. That should bring it up. Hopefully that should get you out of the woods.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your Samsung phone (assuming it is running Android) to share its internet connection with Ubuntu. I have only used this feature to share a 3G connection, so I cannot speak to its functionality with a mobile phone's wifi connection, but it would be worth a try.

Connect your phone to your computer via USB - select the Charge Only option. On your phone, go into Settings-->Wireless & Networks and turn Internet Connection Mode on. Within a few seconds, the new network option should appear in Ubuntu.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi No i am using samsung mobile but its not with android . Thanks for answer .

Comment: No problem, sorry I could not be of more assistance!

Comment: @GrSr So which OS and phone are we talking about? This will bring us much quicker to a solution. If you can't tell make a photo of it and post it in your question.

Comment: @LiveWireBT any help , i need it still .:(