# Help me to make my wifi work in lenovo ideapad 330s

Tags: wireless

Please teach me a step by step method on how to connect my wifi on my lenovo ideapad 330s. It says `Wifi adapter not found.` Im using ubuntu LTS 20.04

> `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
03:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8621] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [17aa:3808]
Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
```

**Edit:**

> `ip link show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000`

link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000

link/ether 8a:d4:d7:81:dd:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

> `sudo ip link set dev usb0 down`

```
`Cannot find device "usb0"`
```

I'm also unable to connect  to the internet using USB and Bluetooth tethering. It says `Activation of network connection failed.`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Im sorry, I'm a completely newbie on ubuntu OS. I already edited it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I cannot use ethernet, my pc have hdmi and I dont have usb to ethernet adapter yet. Is there anyway I can make it work without connecting my pc to internet first?

Comment: Connect your phone and this will give you a temporary connection.

Comment: Im sorry, connect via usb cable? Im confused

Comment: Yes, with a USB cable.

Comment: I tried it, I also disabled secure boot as what they said. And this is what the output on the terminal:

Comment: Its below the question

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add output. Select the text and use `{}` to format.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` first. And also `build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)` is not needed for 20.04.

Comment: To aid in connecting your phone see this: [How to use mobile wi-fi to connect Internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182272/how-to-use-mobile-wi-fi-to-connect-internet)

Comment: `{}` is an icon above the box where you post the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://medium.com/@kimiyukiyukawa/installing-rtl8821ce-network-controller-on-ubuntu-335d8ccb8a92):

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms
sudo m-a prepare
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
reboot
```

You could also try:

**Show Applications** gnome menu ->
Enter into **Search** field **Additional** keyword
and open **Additional Drivers** (opened tab in **Software & Updates** window will appear).
Look if there's your wifi-drivers present.

> Some new Yoga laptops (like the Yoga 530) come with rtl8821ce as the
>   Wi-Fi/Bluetooth chip. But the ideapad-laptop module, which may come
>   included in your distribution, may conflict with this driver. To
>   disable:
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
> ```

For USB tethering, try mac address changing:

- First of all try a different cables
- `ip link show` - run in terminal to see what devices it shows
- Connect your phone to your laptop and enable USB tethering
- `ip link show` - run in terminal to see changes (the new `usb0` network device appeared in my case):

  ```
  4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 7a:20:09:6d:dd:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```
- `sudo ip link set dev usb0 down`

  ```
  4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 7a:20:09:6d:dd:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```
- `sudo ip link set dev usb0 address 8a:20:09:6d:dd:a1`
- `sudo ip link set dev usb0 up`

  ```
  4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 8a:20:09:6d:dd:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```

  As you can see, I've changed my usb0 network adapter's mac address from `7a` to `8a` at the beginning of it.

Comment: When I try to usb tether it only says "Activation of network connection failed".

Comment: I follow almost every tutorials in yt and I've also researched here and it doesnt work. Help me.

Comment: try a different phone

Comment: I tried it on vivo and oppo, both doesnt work.

Comment: My laptop is lenovo, do I need also a lenovo phone to make it work?

Comment: Try to change mac address as I've described in the answer and tell if it works or something goes wrong again. Try to explain steps you've tried in details by editing your answer.

Comment: I edited it and it shows above. Im sorry i dont know how to highlight but thats what it resulted after i inputed your instructions in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to `Software and Updates`.
2. Click the `Additional Drivers` tab.
3. Enable the appropriate wifi driver -> Something like this `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac`, as mentioned in question.
4. Click `Apply changes`.

Comment: Im not yet connected to internet, I tried usb tethering but it only says "Activation of network connection failed." How can i resolve this?

Comment: Use an external adapter temporarily or an Ethernet connection.

Comment: Also, Did you found your wifi card in the list.

Comment: I have hdmi and i dont have usb to ethernet adapter yet. How can I find my wifi card?

Comment: You need to check for your wifi card which is `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac` in the `Additional Drivers` tab in the `Software and Updates` app.

Comment: This won't work without an internet connection. So, you will need an external card.

Comment: Also, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in the terminal before this.

Comment: I can't tether my cp's internet to my laptop. I guess I'll buy first an usb to ethernet adapter to connect my pc to internet and follow your instructions. Thankyou sir.